# WEBrick alter HTTP response headers on a per-file extension basis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Is it possible to modify the `WEBrick` HTTP response headers globally for a specific file extension, for example to serve **all** files with `svgz` extension to include the HTTP Header "**Content-Encoding: gzip**" in the HTTP response? I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**lib/dps/compression.rb**

```
module Dps 
  class Compression
    def initialize(app)  
      @app = app  
    end  

    def call(env)  
      status, headers, response = @app.call(env)
      if File.extname(env['REQUEST_URI']) == ".svgz" && status == 200 
        headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip"
      else
        nil 
      end 
      [status, headers, response]
    end  
  end 
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
config.middleware.insert_before("ActionDispatch::Static", "Dps::Compression")
```

Comment: Ah @dps, now I understand better what you really were looking for... In that case, a custom middleware is probably a good idea, just take in care: a middleware is a new element to your entire (Rails) stack, so every request will run this code. I thought you just need and endpoint to fetch this kind of files... Your original question is perhaps little descriptive :) Would be nice if you edit a bit the original question and title... PD. I don't understand your last edition to this answer.

Comment: Markets thank you for all of your help today.  You are a good soul for spending so much time on this for me.  I have removed my final edit (it turns out it was extraneous), and modified the original question for clarity.

Comment: you're welcome! that's why community matters :) Thanks for clarify your OP.